# gcc - how to create an so from a source file and other o files?

Tags: c, makefile, linker, shared-libraries

I am working on a c project. https://github.com/eantoranz/gitmod It's broken up into separate c/h files. In my current Makefile, I take each one of the c files and compile them into their own .o file, then when I want to create the final program, I ask to compile a c file that has a main and provide all the other .o files. So far, so good (let me know if this approach is not correct).

As a next step, I want to separate the main part of the program from all the other pieces of the code and would like to pack all of the previous o files into a single so file (that had been compiled as just another .o file so far).

So, old approach was like this:

```
gitmod.o: src/gitmod.c include/gitmod.h lock.o root_tree.o thread.o object.o cache.o
    $(CC) -c -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS)

gitmod: src/main.c gitmod.o
    $(CC) $< *.o -o $@ $(CFLAGS)
```

These would be the last 2 steps of this process using the so replacing `gitmod.o` for `libgitmod.so`, after creating all the previous .o files:

```
libgitmod.so: src/gitmod.c include/gitmod.h lock.o root_tree.o thread.o object.o cache.o
    $(CC) $< *.o -shared -o $@ $(CFLAGS)

gitmod: src/main.c libgitmod.so
    $(CC) $< -llibgitmod.so -o $@ $(CFLAGS)
```

`libgitmod.so` would be the shared library that I would like to actually contain all the other sections of code (I really hope that is possible).

When `make` is going through `libgitmod.so`, I am getting this:

```
gcc src/gitmod.c *.o -shared -o libgitmod.so -Iinclude `pkg-config fuse3 libgit2 glib-2.0 --cflags --libs` -DGITMOD_DEBUG -Wall -g
/usr/bin/ld: object.o: warning: relocation against `stderr@@GLIBC_2.2.5' in read-only section `.text'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccir4Ou9.o: relocation R_X86_64_PC32 against symbol `stderr@@GLIBC_2.2.5' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile:32: libgitmod.so] Error 1
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-fPIC`, which means Position Indepent Code, flags is required to create shared object.
You can add the flag in the compile flag, then you can create a shared object.